# How to add and remove value from url using toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, when the user click on toggle to show content, I want to add a hash and id to the url (http://www.somedomain.com/test.html#2111) . When closed I want to remove the #2111.

How do i do that using the toggle?

CSS

```
.toggle{
    display:inline-block;
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
    background:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pixelmixer/basic/48/plus-icon.png");
}
.toggle:after{
    content:"View All";
    display:block;
    height:48px;
    line-height:48px;
    width:288px;
    margin-left:48px;
}
.toggle.expanded:after{
     content:"Close All";
}
.toggle.expanded {
    background:url("http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_32.png");
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var $content = $("div.moreinfo").hide();

            $(".toggle").on("click", function (e) {
                $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
                if($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
                    $("div.plus").hide().removeClass("closed");
                    $("div.minus").show().addClass("opened");   

                } else {

                    $("div.plus").show().addClass("closed");    
                    $("div.minus").hide().removeClass("opened");


                }
                $content.slideToggle();

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set `location.hash` equal to an empty string:

```
location.hash = '';
```

or set it to a value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $content = $("div.moreinfo").hide();
    $(".toggle").on("click", function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
        if($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
           location.hash = someValue;
        } else {
           location.hash = '';
        }
        $content.slideToggle();

    });
});
```

Comment: thanks I had updated with ur code , but only problem is that it doesnt remove the #. after adding #somevalue. because of the hash isnt removed from url.. it jumps around the page..Is there a way to remove the hash so when i click on togle close open it own jump up..

Comment: No problem! There is no way to remove the the hash from the url without reloading the page. Perhaps you could give the element you want the user to be scrolled to an id and instead of setting to `''` you could set it to that id `targetElement`